# Temporary R+W CIFS share for non-root accounts?

Tags: thunderbird, file-sharing, cifs

I want to set up a cross platform mail client (Thunderbird), and so far I want to use NAS as a profile store.

The NAS is CIFS based, and can be mounted on both Windows and Ubuntu. Also the locking works fine for mutex, and setup seems to work as a proof of concept.

The problem is the Linux mount.

Since I'm using a laptop, I'm not always connected to network, hence, I can't use the `/etc/fstab` to set up CIFS share with a modified group id. And the share has to be mounted using `mount -t cifs ...`, which causes it to be owned by root, and owned so badly, that it can't be `chown`ed to the regular user account.

This causes read only issues for Thunderbird, which seem to be solved if Thunderbird is launched via `sudo`.

But I would like to avoid that and use a script to mount the share on-demand to a profile location, with profile based privileges and access rights.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resorted to fstab mount as per http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares

Turns out there are no negative consequences if the share is not available during the bootup, and if network appears later, the share is mounted automatically.

Also, I had to update to Thunderbird 11.0 via PPA to get it to understand the newer profile from Windows PC.